# The Wifi on the Android Q is not getting connected with the provided configuration

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

For Android Q device the WifiManager AddNetwork API gets depreciated. So we referred the documentation.

For AddNetwork : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration) 
Says to use the WifiNetworkSpecifier and AddNetworkSuggestion.

If i use the same the the wifi network on the suggestion list is not get added on the device.

It asked for the username and password when connecting [These configuration is already set programatically]

Also gone through another documentation which says how to connect wifi on Android Q device using WifiNetworkSpecifier using connecting manager.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap#java

This is also getting the same result.

Used same type of codes which have been used on the above two link.

Note: The project is in Xamarin.Android (C#).

Expected result: The wifi has to be connected with the given configured values.

Actual result: the wifi is not connecting, and it asked for the user name and password manually.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried here?

Comment: @CherryBu I have queried the same on this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140469685 . And the codes were as same as in the https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap#java.

Comment: Can you post some C# code here? You use Visual Studio to create xamarin.android project?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Yes, i Use VisualStudio 2019 for this. For codes, i will edit my post with code snippets.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT this issue has confirmed and it will be fixed on upcoming android release. you can check on this link : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140469685

Comment: yes, I have saw it, Thanks for sharing this info.